# Has Mojave broken Applescript: set volume output volume?

Tags: applescript, audio, mojave

```
set volume output volume 25
```

I've used that simple code for well over a decade to set my Mac's audio to a specific volume (25, on a scale of 0-100), but since upgrading to Mojave, running it causes no change.  The volume remains where it was already at, unchanged.

Is set volume output volume broken in Mojave?

Is there a workaround?

EDIT: The problem appears to be with my Apogee Duet (firewire).  I realize it's not supported for Mojave, but it wasn't supported for Sierra or High Sierra either though it worked perfectly and Apogee said it should continue to work with Mojave.  In fact, it does work with Mojave except, there's something odd happening with the correlation between the volume that plays and the display of the volume in system prefs.  The volume that plays is correct.  The volume output shown in the Sound menubar icon and in system prefs no longer has any effect when changed.  Mac OS shows that my Duet is chosen for sound output, but when the Duet is chosen, the Output Volume in sound prefs no longer correlates to the Duet's output volume.

Volume Up / Down / Mute keyboard keys work, but the slider in the Sound menubar icon and in system prefs no longer works, and Applescript for system volume output volume no longer works.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Still working on my Mojave machine.

Comment: what is your full script

Comment: That is literally my full script: set volume output volume 25